# how to select the min value using having key word

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, mysql

I have created the table stu_dep_det

```
CREATE TABLE  `stu_dept_cs` (
  `s_d_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `stu_name` varchar(15) , `gender` varchar(15) , `address` varchar(15),`reg_no` int(10) ,
  `ex_no` varchar(10) ,
  `mark1` varchar(10) ,
  `mark2` varchar(15) ,
  `mark3` varchar(15) ,
  `total` varchar(15) ,
  `avg` double(2,0),
  PRIMARY KEY  (`s_d_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

then Inserted the values

```
INSERT INTO `stu_dept_cs` (`s_d_id`, `stu_name`, `gender`, `address`, `reg_no`, `ex_no`, `mark1`, `mark2`, `mark3`, `total`, `avg`) VALUES
(1, 'alex', 'm', 'chennai', 5001, 's1', '70', '90', '95', '255', 85),
(2, 'peter', 'm', 'chennai', 5002, 's1', '80', '70', '90', '240', 80),
(6, 'parv', 'f', 'mumbai', 5003, 's1', '88', '60', '80', '228', 76),
(7, 'basu', 'm', 'kolkatta', 5004, 's1', '85', '95', '56', '236', 79);
```

I want to select the min(avg) using having keyword and I have used the following sql statement

```
SELECT * FROM stu_dept_cs s  having  min(avg)
```

Is it correct or not plz write the correct ans....

Comment: what is the field of grouping by , having work with group by

Comment: You'd better fix your datamodel, that's where the problem starts. Don't use VARCHAR when you need INT and don't done store the same data in different columns (mark1, mark2, mark3) and don't store the sum and average of these columns when it can be calculated when needed. Your current datamodel will become a huge problem!

Comment: take the @Frank's advice serious.

Answer (score 5):

```
select somecolumn1,somecolumn2
from stu_dept_cs 
group by somecolumn1,somecolumn2,avg
having avg = min(avg)
```

or

```
with t1
(select rownumber() over (partition by somecolumn1,somecolumn2 
    order by somecolumn1,somecolumn2,avg asc) as rownum
from stu_dept_cs )
select * from t1 where rownum=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.* FROM stu_dept_cs t1
LEFT JOIN stu_dept_cs t2
ON t1.avg > t2.avg
WHERE t2.stu_name IS NULL;
```