# SQL query not returning desired result in group by having clause

Tags: mysql

I have a table with member_information and their referring agent. I want to run a query which returns all information in the table (select *) where the agent appears more than 3 times.

my initial query is:

```
SELECT agent FROM activity GROUP BY agent ASC HAVING COUNT(agent) > 3;
```

this returns the agent id's needed but not the rest of the data within 'activity'.

I modified to:

```
SELECT * FROM activity GROUP BY agent ASC HAVING COUNT(agent) > 3
```

this only returns one of the results for each agent number needed instead of all rows with matching agent numbers.

What am I missing?

## edit

assume table structure is as follows:

```
id     |     agent     |     name     |     address 
--------------------------------------------------------
1      |      1        |     (name)   |     (an address)
2      |      1        |     (name)   |     (an address)
3      |      2        |     (name)   |     (an address)
4      |      3        |     (name)   |     (an address)
5      |      3        |     (name)   |     (an address)
6      |      3        |     (name)   |     (an address)
7      |      1        |     (name)   |     (an address)
8      |      2        |     (name)   |     (an address)
9      |      4        |     (name)   |     (an address)
```

the results of the query should return:

```
id     |     agent     |     name     |     address 
--------------------------------------------------------
1      |      1        |     (name)   |     (an address)
2      |      1        |     (name)   |     (an address)
4      |      3        |     (name)   |     (an address)
5      |      3        |     (name)   |     (an address)
6      |      3        |     (name)   |     (an address)
7      |      1        |     (name)   |     (an address)
```

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: look at the answer, you can apply the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537255/how-to-select-the-min-value-using-having-key-word/4537276#4537276

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM ACTIVITY x
  JOIN (SELECT t.agent 
          FROM ACTIVITY t 
      GROUP BY t.agent 
        HAVING COUNT(t.agent) > 3) y ON y.agent = x.agent
```

Answer (score 1):

When you group by, all the rows in a group get condensed into one.  Depending on what you're trying to do, you need to use  the appropriate group functions (SUM, GROUP_CONCAT, etc.), or you can do what I think you're trying to do with a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM activity WHERE agent IN (select agent from activity group by agent asc having count(agent) > 3);
```